# "Numeric overflow in expression” when using android resources

Tags: java, android, warnings, android-resources

I've declared two integer resources as such:

```
<resources>
    <integer name="COLUMNS">5</integer>
    <integer name="ROWS">4</integer>
</resources>
```

When I try to calculate the resulting number of cells (0 based) like this:

```
R.integer.COLUMNS * R.integer.ROWS-1
```

I get the warning `Numeric overflow in expression`

Can anyone explain to me why this warning occurs and if its valid or even dangerous (crash, buffer overflow etc.)?

---

Android Studio 3.3
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772, built on December 25, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.integer.COLUMNS` is the integer **id** of the resource and not the **value** of the resource. 
You can get the value of the resource with:

```
getResources().getInteger(R.integer.COLUMNS)
```